# Reading a CSV mixed string and number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the dataset listed below, and I am trying to read it using panda.read_csv tool as described, but the it's raise the following error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1: invalid start byte.

I imagine that it could be because the column 1 (sample) mix stings with numbers.

So what would be the best way to transform the column 1 in to string before to input it in the pandas ?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

[DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaims.png)

Comment: Can you show a sample of your csv file and dataframe? `data=[ID;Sample;...]` is not valid python syntax.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, I am still learning how to format the questions! Sorry!

Comment: @panktijk now as a picture showing the data in excel datasheet

Comment: @ALollz now it reads, but are not separating the data in the right way

Comment: You can specify your delimiter if it is something else apart from a comma. E.g., for tab separated files, you can add `sep='\t'`

Comment: Well not quite sure you have comma separated values... Try `pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='latin-1', decimal=',', sep=';')`

Comment: @panktijk thanks so much...now it's work, I change the separator from comma to semicolon and now it's work very well

Comment: @ALollz thanks! now it's work very well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error doesn't have to do with mixed numbers and letters, pandas will just read that in as a string.

Without seeing your file, there's not a way to be sure, but there is apparently some character in your input file that is not a valid unicode character. I would double check the character encoding, and open the file just in a text editor instead of excel to see what the first few characters are.

For example, I created a test file containing

```
col1,col2,col3
1,foo,1a
2,bar,2
3,baz,c
4,sit,4d
```

and run `pd.read_csv('testfile.txt')`

output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       foo     1a
1   2       bar     2
2   3       baz     c
3   4       sit     4d
```

Comment: I have edited the question showing the original dataset in excel, please can you check it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, a picture of the text doesn't help, it matters what it looks like before excel sees it. If you could open it in notepad or another text editor and post the first few lines that might help, or check the character encoding as in http://codeftw.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-find-character-encoding-of-text.html

Comment: I changed the first column (0) from ID to seq...and now it' reading but not in the right way separating all the collumns

Comment: data = [seq;Sample;X;Y;Date;Place;Final Depth;Local Depth;Top Depth;Bottom Depth;Method;Project
1;1A;1;2;23/08/2017;Place1;-14;-12,2;0;-1;Cup Extractor;AA
2;1B;2;3;23/08/2017;Place2;-14;-12,2;-1;-2;Cup Extractor;AA
3;2;3;4;23/08/2017;Place3;-14;-11,76;0;-1;Cup Extractor;AA]